# Notification from last year

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

*An edit was suggested to your post Replace last occurence of character in string, please review it.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497333/295783

last edit was in March 2011...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1254373) was proposed about an hour ago and got rejected by the community before you got the notification (they're not destroyed if it gets acted upon before you see it).

Comment: What's the trick to find the suggested edit? I don't see it in the edit history for the answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith: You have to use Tim Stone's Patented Magical Powers Kit (or just browse through the history in the suggested edits queue).

Comment: Ah thanks. Thought this might be some hidden feature like the timeline (which it doesn't appear on).

Comment: Interestingly enough the edit was valid ;)